# Correct usage Of LOG4J in Spring Framework Via DI

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I am trying to use Log4j as part of the Spring Framework,
as far as i understand through the use of a an appropriate bean
the system is supposed to map a singleton instance accessible in the code
while mapping the logging depth automatically to the class

Similar to the normal use of Log4J as in

`Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());`

i have been using the following Spring bean definition

```
<bean id="log4jInitialization"
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass"
        value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>conf\log4j.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But i am unable to map this bean to a specific member in a given class
nor am i able to use it through @autowired

Please let me know if there are any better ways to integrate Log4j and Spring

Best Regards

Mark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that log4j is not DI friendly.

The `Log4jConfigurer.initLogging()` method has a void return value, so there's nothing to inject. The idea is that you call that method, which bootstraps log4j, and then you use the Log4j API as usual (using `Logger.getLogger(getClass())`).

You generally wouldn't configure `Log4jConfigurer` as a Spring bean, though, but more usually you'd invoke it directly from your own code during application startup.

If this is a webapp, then Spring provides alternatives to `Log4jConfigurer` that are better suited to that environment (`Log4jWebConfigurer`, `Log4jConfigListener`).

Incidentally, 2 years ago I filed a [feature request](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-4431) to allow loggers to be autowired, and it's finally been marked as fix for Spring 3.1. Horray.

Comment: Thanks. Hope that your suggestion is implemented in the near future. By the way i saw log5j found a system to automatically execute "Logger.getLogger(getClass())"  hope Spring Community find a similar but better way - Log5j did some dangerous stuff to achieve this