# SimpleMappingExceptionResolver with logging without Java code

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logging, exception

I want to implement exception handling in my Spring MVC application. I chose SimpleMappingExceptionResolver, because this is the most clear solution. The only problem is that in all the tutorials and examples I found logging is implemented with Java code like the following:

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyExceptionHandler.class);
```

I don't think this is a good way, so I am asking if there is any way to do this without java code, using some kind of xml configuration, etc?

Comment: This is not implementing logging code in java as such. You are just telling the logger that I am in this file, and will post logs for it. Why is this one line causing you so much heart burn is what I can't understand?

Comment: Because I have multiple controllers in my application and as a result there would be multiple definition of this logger. Why can't I make all this somehow autowired?

Comment: Then this answers your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171762/correct-usage-of-log4j-in-spring-framework-via-di  . As the answer says, The short answer to your question is that log4j is not DI friendly. And I still don't think it's a big problem.

The Log4jConfigurer.initLogging() method has a void return value, so there's nothing to inject. The idea is that you call that method, which bootstraps log4j, and then you use the Log4j API as usual (using Logger.getLogger(getClass())).